# Override template and block from a module?

Tags: blocks, template, overrides

I am developing a newsletter extension. I try to override the template

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

and the block `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info` to replace the Newsletter block with my own.

[image]

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to override only this selected section? Am I right here ? 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9JxJ7glqSXNDi2TrtZAonc_OyrQ7QJO/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Yes, thats true. But I think I am forced to override "Contact information" too since they are in the same template.

Comment: Please check my answer. If it will helpful to you then you can approve my answer, and if you want more help then you can ask me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="Vendor_Module::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>        
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Override Block in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php`. Override functions from below file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Account\Dashboard;

class Info extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info
{
}
```

Override template in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

You can create new module and override that file otherwise you do that using custom theme as well.

I'll show you here how can we override template file using custom module.

Please create Vendor name directory first, and move into that and create another directory Module.

Then you need to create `registration.php` file here.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

Content for this file is ..

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

After that please create one more directory there `etc` here and add `module.xml` file there..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

After that please create `view` directory there and move into that and create `frontend` move into that.

create `layout` directory and add `customer_account_index.xml` this file there..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::account/dashboard/info.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

After creating this file please go back once and create `templates` directory here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates

and add `info.phtml` file here in this path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

Content for this file is ..

```
<div class="block block-dashboard-info">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Account Information')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="box box-information">
            <strong class="box-title">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span>
            </strong>
            <div class="box-content">
                <p>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getName()) ?><br>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getEmail()) ?><br>
                </p>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.account.dashboard.info.extra'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="box-actions">
                <a class="action edit" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/account/edit')) ?>">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit')) ?></span>
                </a>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getChangePasswordUrl()) ?>" class="action change-password">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password')) ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()) : ?>
            <div class="box box-newsletter">
                <strong class="box-title">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Newsletters')) ?></span>
                </strong>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <p>
                        <?php if ($block->getIsSubscribed()) : ?>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You are subscribed to "General Subscription".')) ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You aren\'t subscribed to our newsletter.')) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-actions">
                    <a class="action edit" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('newsletter/manage')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit')) ?></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this template file you can change anything whatever you want there.

**You can override your block here**

For that you need to create `di.xml` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is ...

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" />
</config>
```

Then after you need to create `Info.php` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php

Content for this file is ..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Account\Dashboard;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Info extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info
{
    public function myCustomFunction(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here I've created my custom function and override default `Info.php` file we do not need to copy whole file just extend parent class and you can create your custom functions there.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you. It worked. This shows how to override the template. But the info on how to override the block is missing. E.g. what if I want to change or add a method in the block class `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm adding that within few mins

Comment: Please check updated answer, If it helps you, you can approve my answer. :)

Comment: If you need more help, you can ask me

Comment: Thank you very much sir, your solution is really good explained! Problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks Buddy!! You are always welcome. Happy to help you. :)

Comment: I decided to accept the answer from @Ranganathan because it is a bit simpler and you don't need the extra file di.xml. It is awesome that you can solve the problem in multiple ways, but I like to keep it simple. I hope you don't mind, thank you again!

Comment: It's Okay not an issue.