# How to override template in newsletter/manage?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, overrides, magento2.3.2

I try to override the following template which is under **www.example.net/newsletter/manage** with my own

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/newsletter.phtml
```

**Block class:** `Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter`

I already asked the question [Override template and block from a module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293440/override-template-and-block-from-a-module), and I understood it. But I struggle to find out, how to override this one.

[image]

I added my custom template file `newsletter.phtml` to my module:

> app\code\Black\Newsletter2Go\view\frontend\templates\form\newsletter.phtml

What step is required next? I guess I need to add a layout file too, but how do I know how it has to be named?

I need a walkthrough for this one please so that I can understand how this all works together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If @Rising answer not work try this. In `newsletter_manage_index.xml`
try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer_newsletter">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::form/newsletter.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**OR**

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_newsletter" template="Vendor_Module::form/newsletter.phtml"/>
```

Comment: check updated answer and if its not work then replace <referenceBlock> parth with another solution which I have added

Comment: I edited the answer to fix an error. You have to use `Vendor_Module::form/newsletter.phtml` instead of `Vendor_Module::newsletter.phtml`. Then it works! :) But how do you find out that you need to reference the block *customer_newsletter* ?

Comment: the arguments > argument name="template" can be done via di.xml in some block classes. but this is not a way you would use when working with layout xml. Setting the template directly on the referenceblock would work in most cases, but im pretty sure it wont in this specific case.

Comment: @Ekk4rd, it worked though. I tried it.

Comment: ok nice, good to know... about the customer_newsletter block: take a look into the newsletter_manage_index.xml where the block is defined. Using a layout.xml with the same name, you are able to overwrite a xml node by using the same name attribute.

Comment: @Ekk4rd, yes, but I can't find this layout anywhere. I looked in *module-customer/view/frontend/layout/*

Comment: Oh, my fault. It is in module-newsletter/...

Comment: @RakeshVarma, I will accept your answer as soon as the edit was accepted.

Comment: @Black its depend on where you add your phtml file if you move it directly in view/frontend/templates then no need to add `form` in path.

Comment: @RakeshVarma, I know, but I try to keep the original path for better organisation and to keep it understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to override the following file mentioned below either using theme or by using your custom module.

`/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/form/newsletter.phtml` file.

If you are trying to override using theme then please create the folder structure mentioned below.

```
app/design/frontend/Namespace/<Your Theme Name>/Magento_Customer/templates/form/newsletter.phtml
```

If you are trying to override using Module.

```
app/code/<Namespace>/<Module Name>/view/frontend/templates/form/newsletter.phtml
```

and please add the below line in `newsletter_manage_index.xml` which you need to create in your layout folder.

```
<referenceBlock name="newsletter.custom">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::form/newsletter.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

After clear the cache and see the results.

Comment: Your xml is not complete? Don't I have to use `<page ...><body>...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually in this specific case, overwriting the template by using a module, is a bit more tough then the most other templates in Magento2. Because this one is not set by layout.xml, but directly in the specific Block-Class.
See `module-customer/Block/Newsletter.php` for more information.

The most easy way to overwrite this template would be by using a Magento2 Theme instead of an module. If you would create a theme, you could just place the new templte inside.
`app/deisgn/frontend/Yourtheme/yourtheme/Module_Customer/templates/form/newsletter.phtml`.
How do setup a Magento2 Theme: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html

If you still want to change the template by using a module, i guess you won't be able to do this in this module, by just updating a block inside layout.xml, maybe you even need to write a preference for `Magento\Customer\Block\Newsletter`

*edit:
Utilizing the `<action method="setTemplate">...` should also do it like @Rising mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

you can place this template file into your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Customer/templates/form/newsletter.phtml
```